# Using the drive API how to copy a Spreadsheet without breaking scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API v3 copy function to copy a spreadsheet (as per https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy )

However when the file is copied, while the scripts are also copied, the scripts no longer work and come up with strange errors, such as

[image]

There are occasionally other errors that flash up, but disappear very quickly so I'm not quite sure what they are saying and can't seem to find any log of them.

I'm wondering if this is a bug, or of there is some special trick for copying a google sheets document via the drive API when they have scripts? perhaps a weird permissions thing?

For reference the code that does the copying is using the .NET core google libs to access the API

which I wrote a simple wrapper around :-

```
 public File CopyFile(File destination, string sourceId)
 {
    var copyRequest = _driveService.Files.Copy(destination, sourceId);
    copyRequest.Fields = "id";
    return copyRequest.Execute();
 }
```

which works perfectly for everything so far, except for google sheets and scripts.

The scripts themselves don't seem to have an effect, the simplest script like

```
function onEdit(e){ Logger.log("hi") }
```

won't work.

one interesting thing when it does copy the file, the project doesn't seem to have an owner like the original file it was copied from.  The API is accessed using a google service account which (it seems) isn't a first class user of the "G Suite". Not sure if this is part of the problem or not.

[image]

**UPDATE: 13/Feb/2020**

This is looking like a permissions issue to do with service accounts, I don't quite know how to fully solve it yet.

There's at least three essential steps to start fixing this problem

1. you need to enable "Domain-Wide Delegation" on your service account in your credentials section of the google console
2. You need to get an Admin of the GSuite to give permissions to the service account  as per https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation  The biggest issue is knowing what scopes to assign it, so far I have assigned it `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`  and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
3. In your connection to the API when you authenticate you need to say who you want to impersonate ... C# is as follows...

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = Scopes,
                    User = "realuserinGsuite@yourdoman.wherever"

                }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

This means the service account will act as if it was that user.

This makes the whole thing work.  However there seems to be a nasty side effect, which I'm not quite sure why it exists.  It also occurs if I simply make a copy of the original spreadsheet.   The problem is it takes a LONG time before the script starts working. Once it does start working, it works quickly as normal

looking at the executions it took about 12 minutes before it would start working. I'm not sure why, and I'm not sure if there is an easy fix for this.

So I'm wondering if there is still something I'm doing wrong? or is this just a weird effect that can happen in G-Suite?

[image]

Comment: I tried copying a Spreadsheet with the [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) you provided and I could not reproduce the issue. The project's Owner of the new copy is also correct (me). Can you confirm if this only happens with the .NET library?

Comment: @Jescanellas how did you auth? with a service account or your own account?

Comment: Yes, it also works as intended with a service account copying the file.

Answer (score 2):

#### Situation:

1. Copy the Spreadsheet including the Google Apps Script using the service account.
2. Share the copied Spreadsheet with your Google account.
3. Run the script on your Google account.

By this flow, such issue occurs. From your question and situation, I thought like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In my environment, by above flow, I could replicate your situation. In this case, I could confirm with Google Apps Script as the sample script.

#### Reason of issue:

I think that the reason of this issue is that in order to run the script, the user (owner) is required. Unfortunately, the service account is the user like a dummy user. So the service account cannot be the owner for running the script. So I think that the script is not broken in this situation. And I think that this is the same consideration as you mentioned at the last section in your question. For example, Apps Script API for using the Google Apps Script cannot be used with the service account. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) I think that this might be also be relevant.

#### Workaround:

So as a sample situation, if you want to run the script, how about changing the owner from the service account from the actual user (for example, it's your Google account) and testing it? In my environment, I could confirm that after the Spreadsheet was copied with the service account, when the owner of Spreadsheet is changed from the service account to my Google account, the script worked.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: this looks like what I'm experiencing, I'll be having a look at this again in a few hours so will investigate this and see what I can do to get the owner correct

Comment: @Keith Nicholas Thank you for replying. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I went down the ownership path and found how to get it to work, but still a weird problem that the scripts take a long time to start working

Comment: @Keith Nicholas Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, in my environment, the situation of your updated question cannot be replicated. I apologize for this. When I could replicate it, I would like to think of the reason.